# How can I get unread messages for inbox testing?

Tags: discussion, api, inbox, testing

I use [`/users/{id}/inbox/unread`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-unread-inbox) method to get unread items in a user's inbox. But how could I test it if I have no unread items in my inbox?

How can I get/generate unread messages for testing?

P.S. If there is no sandbox environment for such testings, then I will use your replies and comments on this question to test it ;).

Comment: Stack Exchange sites allow limited sock-puppets.  Create a second account and use it to test for unread messages.  I suggest you also use the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) or answers to this question as targets for the sock posts and make it clear what you are doing.  Don't try to game votes or anything dicey.