# API to Emulate Notifications

Tags: feature-request, api-v2.2, questions, inbox

Is there a API End Point that will emulate Test Notifications? When I say Notifications, I Mean both Inbox and Achievements.

Right now i am using below for the data

**Unread Notification** : https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unread-notifications#filter=default&run=true

**Unread Inbox**: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread#filter=default&run=true

but when there are no notifications to check, it is becoming difficult to assess different conditions

The way that i am doing it in my app right now to test is Call these end points without `unread` see if they are items with `is_unread` is `true` and count all those which are unread and then show it as unread. But when there are no unread messages, only way i could think of is after receiving JSON, modify top 3 items `is_unread` to `true` in code behind.

I Understand if there is no way this can be implemented but i would like to see if this can be achieved from `API` itself so that we can check multiple possibilities.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackapps.com/questions/4850/how-can-i-get-unread-messages-for-inbox-testing